How can I check if a value is in array with Valibot?
I want to validate if the input of a select element is in the array of valid values with Vue + Valibot.
I have a select with numeric values (IDs) and I need to check if is a valid ID.
So first I check if matches the numeric regex, and then I don't know how to add some validator for checking if the value is in the array.
import * as v from "valibot";

const validValues = ['1', '2', '4'];

const Schema = v.object({
  // ...
  user: v.string([v.regex(/^\d+$/)]),
});

Edit:
I just saw the custom validator, and it worked doing:
  user: v.string([
    v.regex(/^\d+$/),
    v.custom((i) => validValues.includes(i), "not valid"),
  ]),

But there is some premade validator that achieves that?

Your solution is good. I don't think there's anything better than this. The best thing I could come up with is:
const validValues = ['1', '2', '4'];

const schema = v.object({
  user: v.union(validValues.map((value) => v.literal(value))),
});

